# How do I find the file with this error in Visual Studio?

Tags: ios, xamarin, kinvey

I'm getting this error in Visual Studio when trying to run the Kinvey Xamarin starter app on my iPhone:

> Error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void
>   PubnubApi.Pubnub::AddListener(PubnubApi.SubscribeCallback)',
>   referenced from the method 'System.Void
>   Kinvey.RealtimeRouter::Initialize(System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,Kinvey.AbstractClient)'
>   in 'PubnubPCL, Version=4.0.2.2, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=dc66f52ce6619f44'. (MT2101) (KXStarterApp.iOS)

I have no idea how to resolve it, but I have a more general question about Visual Studio: how do I find the location of the errors it reports?

The search seems godawful, it never finds anything even when I'm looking directly at it in the editor.

So I just don't know how to start tracking this down. Where do I go to find this file?

Comment: it pretty clearly originates from a Kinvey library - have you contacted them?

Comment: @Jason, that's a good thing to do about the error, but the question itself is broader: how the heck do I find that file? In general I can never fine the files with the errors Visual Studio reports.

Comment: it's coming from inside one of the compiled Kinvey libraries - you don't have access to their source files.  If it was originating from one of your source files it would point you directly to it.

Comment: That's a terrific clarification, if you make it an answer I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error originates from a compiled third party library or nuget package, it doesn't have a source file to refer you to.  If it originates from your own code, the error should point you to a specific file and line.